# useWrappedStore missing in next-redux-wrapper

Tags: redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, next-redux-wrapper

I was trying to implement the next-redux-wrapper with redux-toolkit.
As the example suggests in https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/blob/master/packages/demo-redux-toolkit/pages/_app.tsx.

As the example suggests, the store should be wrapper with the **useWrappedStore** method. Unfortunately, it's not found anywhere in the library.

```
const MyApp: FC<AppProps> = ({Component, ...rest}) => {
    const {store, props} = wrapper.useWrappedStore(rest);
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Component {...props.pageProps} />
        </Provider>
    );
};

export default MyApp;
```

Anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Is your code exactly the same as the example? Where are you importing `wrapper` from?

Comment: Got the solution.. 
[https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/issues/439#issuecomment-991138041]

As they mentioned, their examples uses the version 8.0.0-rc.1 and the main branch is still 7